# Maintaining object relationships with PHP serialization

Tags: php, oop, serialization, relationship

I came across a quite tough problem to solve regarding objects implementing the `Serializable` interface. Let's take an example:

```
class A {
    public $b;
}

class B {
    public $a;
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->b = $b;
$b->a = $a;

echo serialize($a); // O:1:"A":1:{s:1:"b";O:1:"B":1:{s:1:"a";r:1;}}
echo serialize($b); // O:1:"B":1:{s:1:"a";O:1:"A":1:{s:1:"b";r:1;}}

$a = unserialize(serialize($a));
var_export($a === $a->b->a); // true
```

We can see in this example, that when using the built-in PHP serialization feature (whether or not we use the `__sleep()` function), the cross references between `A` & `B` are preserved (`r:1;`).

However, if we want to enforce the use of the Serializable interface, the problem arises:

```
class A implements Serializable  {
    public $b;

    public function serialize() { return serialize($this->b); }
    public function unserialize($s) { $this->b = unserialize($s); }
}

class B implements Serializable {
    public $a;

    public function serialize() { return serialize($this->a); }
    public function unserialize($s) { $this->a = unserialize($s); }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->b = $b;
$b->a = $a;

echo serialize($a); // infinite loop crashes PHP
```

Because each object serialization is independently managed, there is no global way to see whether an object has already been serialized, to create a reference to it. The `serialize()` functions are then called in an infinite loop.

Is there a good workaround for this problem? A pattern to use for the `serialize()` functions?

Comment: That's a nice new PHP *"feature"* you found there. Can't tell you how to resolve it though. I tried assigning references (`$a->b = &$b`), but that also failed.

Comment: That's a purely predictable behaviour, I think that the solution lies in the user code, but can't find a clever way to workaround that for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has been named *cyclic object references* by the Doctrine Project in their documentation on [Serializing entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/architecture.html#serializing-entities):

> Serializable does not work well with any potential cyclic object
>   references (at least we did not find a way yet, if you did, please
>   contact us).

So, as far as I know, there is currently no generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick:

```
function inStack( $cls, $func ) {
    $backTrace = debug_backtrace();
    for( $i = 2; $i < count( $backTrace ); ++$i  ) {
        if( isset( $backTrace[$i][ 'class' ] ) && $backTrace[$i][ 'class' ] == $cls &&
            isset( $backTrace[$i][ 'function' ] ) && $backTrace[$i][ 'function' ] == $func )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class A implements Serializable  {
    public $b;

    public function serialize() {
        if( inStack( 'A', 'serialize' ) ) return '';
        return serialize( $this->b );
    }
    public function unserialize($s) {
        if( $s == '' ) return null;
        $b = unserialize( $s );
        if( $b !== null ) {
            $this->b = $b;
            $this->b->a = $this;
        }
    }
}

class B implements Serializable {
    public $a;

    public function serialize() {
        if( inStack( 'B', 'serialize' ) ) return '';
        return serialize( $this->a );
    }
    public function unserialize($s) {
        if( $s == '' ) return null;
        $a = unserialize( $s );
        if( $a !== null ) {
            $this->a = $a;
            $this->a->b = $this;
        }
    }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->b = $b;
$b->a = $a;

$a = unserialize( serialize( $a ) );
var_dump( $a === $a->b->a ); //true
```

Comment: Wow! Nice technical solution, but isn't your `inStack()` test based only on the class name, and would break if we had to serialize more than one instance of the same class?

Comment: @Benjamin When we call `inStack( 'A', 'serialize' )` from within `A::serialize` it will only return true when we are calling A::serialize recursively. Notice I iterate the trace array starting from index 2 to bypass inStack() itself and our current A::serialize call.

Comment: I still don't feel very confident with using a debug function to provide a stable behavior :S

Comment: @Benjamin Me neither but debug_backtrace() is quite reliable I have been using it in a lot of applications for a long time with no problem, I think it has just been misnamed, it should have been named simply **backtrace()** to keep us mentaly comfortable ;)

Comment: I don't see any "don't use it for serious stuff" notice in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) either.

Comment: You're probably right on this point, though I still feel quite uncomfortable with the idea of using it on an actual project.

Comment: The main problem of this approach is actually the fact that you're manually assigning `$this->a->b` and `$this->b->a` in `unserialize()`, but you don't actually know whether they were equal before serialization (even though they are in this example). Also, this is not a generic approach / reusable code that could be useful elsewhere. I do appreciate your efforts though! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Standard PHP serialization offers two kind of references which work only per the single serialization call in a sequential manner: recursion and recursion ref.

When you implement the `Serializable` interface, you can potentially stretch this across multiple objects and serialization steps as long as you offer one store. When each object in memory for example has an identifier, a central serilaization service can be stuffed with these on serialization and unpacked in even different order on unserialization.

The service can take care of deciding to fetch an object with multiple references to it from the store - or if already unserialized - the runtime object. As the service is central, it can easily decide and the `Serializable` methods can just consume this service.

This does also allow cyclic references. However, you need to implement this on your own because of the mapping.

Taken by the word, the doctrine project actually has this already. Its form of object serialization is the database itself. Just to open the view a little, sure this is not what you look for.